# Gradle Plugin: How to convert all images (resources) before APK is packed

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'd like auto convert all images to webp when build apk.

How to get all images and convert it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i think it's just need to do once, u can right click ur image folder and click the `convert to webp...` menu in `andorid studio 3`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But it only converts our resources, other libraries isn't converted. And I'd like convert in release mode, don't do that in debug mode.